# Adding a Microservice to WSO2 Identity Server as a component

Tags: wso2, microservices, msf4j, wso2-identity-server

I have microservice running independently doing some stuff by talking separately to WSO2 Identity Server. Now I want to add this microservice to Identity server or kind of extending Identity Server to include the capabilities of the microservice so that just starting the WSO2 Identity Server will take care of all my requirements. The microservice was created using msf4j and created as a OSGI bundle following the below link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/MSF4J200/Creating+a+Microservice+as+an+OSGi+Bundle

After creating the bundle, I placed it in the 'repository/components/dropins' folder of the WSO2 Identity Server following the below link.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon447/Config+Files+for+Third+Party+JARs

After placing the bundle, started the Identity Server in '-DosgiConsole' mode hoping that everything will work fine. But typing 'ss *bundle_name*' dint return nothing in the console.

Also the microservice independently ran on 8080 through msf4j. If what I am doing is meaningful and assume somehow I achieved it, at what port the service will run? How will I access the exposed resources?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with the carbon kernel 4.4.x based products or older products since there are some additional MANIFEST headers (e.g carbon-component) that are been used to process at the runtime. This will be added in future wso2 products which will be based on carbon kernel 5.x